# python pandas dataframe missplaced

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

my pandas dataframe is not correctly placing items when i append new row to it.
i use a function to make it easier to append.
also when i append without function it works fine.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH348.png)

code:

```
from emailsender import email_send
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

try:
    file = pd.read_csv("customers.csv")
except:
    pass


customers = {"name":["name"],
             "last":["last"],
             "age_range":[0],
             "emails":["namelast@gmail.com"]}

df_customers = pd.DataFrame(customers)


def add_customer(df,name=np.nan,last=np.nan,age=np.nan,email=np.nan):
    return df.append({"name":name,
                    "last":last,
                    "age_range":age,
                    "emails":email},ignore_index=True)





df_customers = (df_customers,"mohamed","miboun","mohamedwapana@gmail.com")
print(df_customers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only append `Series, df or list-like` objects to a dataframe, but you are appending a dictionary to df. So, try this:

```
...
#your code befor append
...
df_to_add = pd.DataFrame({"name":[name], "last":[last], "age_range":[25], "emails":[email]})

return df.append(df_to_add, ignore_index=True)
```